# WPDB Query - Return meta_value based on _meta_key

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime

Please could someone help with extending the functionality of this code to incorporate the end date of the event as well as the start?

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_content, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_id, $wpdb->postmeta.post_id, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->posts.post_title FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value " );


  foreach ( $result as $page ) {
  $date = new DateTime($page->meta_value);

  if (strtotime($page->meta_value) >= strtotime('monday this week') && strtotime($page->meta_value) < strtotime('monday next week')) {
  echo '<h2><div class="date-title">';
  echo $page->post_title;
  echo '</div><div class="date-date">';
  echo $date->format('d-m-Y').'<br/>';
  echo '</div></h2>';
  } 

  }
  ?>
```

I tried changing

```
WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate'
```

to

```
WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_EventEndDate'
```

This then returns the start date and end date meta keys but im not able to echo these values out separately.

Basically, I would like to output this

```
Event Name starts on (start date here) and finishes on (end date here)
```

for each event.

hope this question is clearer?

Thanks

[EDIT]

The meta keys for the start and end dates are:

`_EventStartDate` and `_EventEndDate` both in wp_postmeta

Thanks

Comment: You question is not clear as what you want to achieve, or what output yu want.

Comment: apologies i will edit

Comment: updated now @Raunak Gupta

Comment: So you want to show post with event start date and end date right? also tell in which key start date and end date are store.

Comment: _EventStartDate and _EventEndDate both in wp_postmeta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get custom post_type post then you can use `WP_Query`, and to get meta's you have to use `get_post_meta()`.
Do some this like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('event'), //<-- Replace it with your custom post_type
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if (!empty($query->posts))
{
    foreach ($query->posts as $post)
    {
        $_EventStartDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_EventStartDate', TRUE);
        $_EventEndDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_EventEndDate', TRUE);
        echo $post->post_title . ' starts on ' . $_EventStartDate . ' and finishes on ' . $_EventEndDate;
        //...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey, @Raunak Gupta, this works, however, the reason I used wpdb, in the end, was because the wp_query is limited to future dates only. The way I have it setup at the moment I can use the if statement with strtotime to filter out the date range I need, any idea on how to achieve things this way around or tweak the above query?

Comment: @Jonnygogo: pardon I couldn't able to get you. what does "wp_query is limites to future dates" means ??

Comment: I believe that using wpdb bypasses all that's configured by the plugin thus letting you do what you want with all the dates in the db

Comment: pressed "enter" to soon, refresh and youll see my edit